# download to local storage android phonegap 3.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, cordova-3

I have this code below for downloading a jpg into my local storage but i'm not getting any file downloaded 
i have the following plugins installed

- cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
- cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
      <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
      <title>Hello World</title>

  </head>
    <body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="painlessfs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var url = 'http://2d-code.co.uk/images/google-qr-code.jpg';
  var filePath = 'file:///android_asset/www/res/db/"';
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
  var uri = encodeURI(url);

  fileTransfer.download(
      uri,
      filePath,
      function(entry) {
          alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
      },
      function(error) {
          alert("download error source " + error.source);
          alert("download error target " + error.target);
          alert("upload error code" + error.code);
      },
      false,
      {
          headers: {
              "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
          }
      }
  );

  </script>
  ```

after this i ran phonegap build android and installed my apk in my device didn't receive any alerts. kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run your code when deviceReadyevent triggers:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
        //Your code goes here
}
```

It should look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
    var url = 'http://2d-code.co.uk/images/google-qr-code.jpg';
    var filePath = 'file:///android_asset/www/res/db/"';
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(url);

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        filePath,
        function(entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("download error source " + error.source);
            alert("download error target " + error.target);
            alert("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        false,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Read more about it [**here**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

Comment: i am only getting error alerts can u help me were am i wrong ?

Comment: Have you configured your Android application so it can access internet?

Comment: yes i have during installation I get Network communication and storage access

Comment: download error source http://2d-code.co.uk/images/google-qr-code.jpg |
download error target null |
upload error code 1

Comment: Let me give a look at this code, I will contact you as soon as I find a problem.